# Animating Text widget content based on change of variable

Tags: flutter

How can I animate the change from a Text widget with a particular String to a new String which is dynamic, i.e., I don't know what it'll be beforehand ?

For example, let the widget be `Text('a')`. Later I want it to animate to `Text('b')`, maybe a after a button being clicked by a user.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user input in a variable and display it in the Text widget. For example,

```
 var input = value;
```

inside the widget you can use Text('$input') or directly Text(input) to display it

Comment: But won't that make a sudden change ? I need the transition to be smooth

Comment: you can use timer function in between or else see if this can help you https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit